# CakePHP 3 and jsGrid - failed AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, jsgrid

When using jsGrid, the controller of the script uses ajax to load, add, edit and delete data. However, currently when I attempt to add data, it fails to save to the database, and the grid shows up as blank.

[image: jsGrid initial]

This screenshot is my initial jsGrid when I start a new line in the jsGrid and enter some data.

When I click the green + button, the data is saved to the jsGrid, and no data is saved to the mySQL database.

This is my jsGrid script:

```
<div id="jsGrid"></div>
    <script>
         var id = "<?php echo $id?>" //the id being passed to the View.
         var resources = [];

        var instruments = [
            {Name: "", Id: 0},
            {Name: "Drum Kit", Id: 1},
            {Name: "Guitar", Id: 2},
            {Name: "Piano", Id: 3},
            {Name: "Violin", Id: 4},
        ];

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            controller: {
                loadData: function (filter) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "<?= $host.$basepath ?>/instrument/",
                        data: filter
                    });
                },
                insertItem: function (item) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?= $host.$basepath ?>/instrument/",
                        data: item
                    });
                },
                updateItem: function (item) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "PUT",
                        url: "<?= $host.$basepath ?>/instrument/",
                        data: item
                    });
                },
                deleteItem: function (item) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "DELETE",
                        url: "<?= $host.$basepath ?>/instrument/",
                        data: item
                    });
                }
            },

            width: "100%",
            height: "400px",

            inserting: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,

            data: resources,

            fields: [
                        {
                             name: "Instrument",
                             type: "select",
                             items: instruments,
                             valueField: "Id",
                             textField: "Name",
                             validate: "required",
                             width: 175
                        },
                        {name: "Comment", type: "text", width: 150},
                        {name: "resource_id", type: "text", width: 150, visible: false,
                                        insertTemplate: function() {
                                            var input = this.__proto__.insertTemplate.call(this);
                                            input.val(id)
                                            return input;
                                    }},
                        {type: "control"}
                    ]
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

`$host.$basepath` are two variables set in the AppController which refer to my host and the base of my project respectively. `resource_id` as an input is to ensure the foreign key to the Resources table is filled in.

The controller portion of the script comes from the [PHP sample of jsGrid](https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid-php/blob/master/public/js/sample.js).

When I do an Inspect console, my console.log of the item being added is as follows:

[image: jsGrid Add item inspect]

I do have AJAX already implemented in my config/routes.php, as per this [page](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions) in the CakePHP 3 Cookbook:

```
$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml']);
```

And my AppController already has Request Handler in the initialize function, as per this [page](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html), which is passed down to all other controllers:

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

**Update:** I've removed the `return` from the ajax which fixes the saving and updating to jsGrid errors, however still none of the Ajax callbacks work.